# Swapping labels vs. particles in wavefunctions

Tags: wavefunction, symmetry, fermions

I have been told that (for example) identical fermion wavefunctions need to be anti-symmetric under exchange of particle. I have also been told that identical fermion wavefunctions need to be anti-symmetric under exchange of fermion label. Because these are identical particles are these both true, and mean the same thing? Or is one more correct than the other?

Comment: Exchange of particles is implemented by permuting (or exchanging) labels.

Comment: Found an answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245684/why-does-exchanging-coordinates-produce-a-phase-of-pm-1-in-an-identical-parti